# Which certificates does Java trust by default with HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, https

If I open a `HttpsURLConnection` by opening a `java.net.URL` connection to, say, https://www.google.com/ how does Java decide whether to trust the certificate chain?

Are there some kind of defaults hard-coded into the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There comes a *Truststore* with a Java installation. You can use Oracle's *keytool* to query the there installed certificates (I think the password is empty, or 'changeit').

Answer (score 3):

For development purpose , you can add self signed certificate to the Java trusted X509 certificate repo like:

```
cd PathToJRE/lib/security

sudo keytool -import -keystore cacerts -alias anAlias -file aCertificat
```

default password is changeIt

But for production is not recommended, you will get into errors like bad defined certificate, etc. You can create some utility class that take care of TrustManager and HostnameVerifier

Answer (score 0):

There is a file cacert in the security folder of the JRE which contains defaults certificates